# free windows installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation

I have found a lot of programs to make an installation package for .net application but non of them meet my requirements.

I'm looking for a **free** application which is able to create installation and uninstallation package and is able to check if net framework and sql 2008 Redistributable is installed if not application should be able to install them first and then start application installation process

Comment: Do you need them additional packages to be bundled with the installation or they should be downloaded from internet?

Comment: They should be downloaded from internet

Comment: Soooo....what was wrong with Windows Installer?

Comment: Windows Installer is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

It is free, but the initial learning curve may be a little bit harder then other programms. The output of WiX is a *.msi package.

Comment: We have used Wix for years, it is very powerful, but as PetPaulsen suggests it has an initial learning curve. Once you're over that it can do virtually anything you want!

Comment: yep I saw it but it doesn't detect vs 2010 on my PC, if I run it manually unhandled exception window pops-up

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) - I compared it once with NSIS and found it more usable. It suports scripting, and you will find example scripts for installation of .NET and other redistributables through the search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [installer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353), that is shipped with visual studio? If it is very simple, try [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). Aslo, consider [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

Or [Windows Installer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288)?

If you have Visual Studio installed then you can simply create a setup project within your solution. If not, then download from the above link (or fine the appropriate version to download) and utilise the set creation application manually.