# How do I make my program show up in apps and features?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am a c# developer and I would like to know how I can make my application show up in the apps and features section of the settings in windows.

Comment: Install it by any installer you like

Comment: To show up under apps & features, it has to have the ability to be uninstalled. Programs of that kind register themselves in the Register (see `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`). You should probably not try to do this yourself. Use as installer setup program such as [Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983751/2791540)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using what John Wu said I have made a solution to this.

This code adds a program entry to the registry at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall".

Library:
`using Microsoft.Win32`

Main Code:

```
RegistryKey software = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
RegistryKey microsoft = software.OpenSubKey("Microsoft");
RegistryKey windows = microsoft.OpenSubKey("Windows");
RegistryKey currentversion = windows.OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion");
RegistryKey uninstall = currentversion.OpenSubKey("Uninstall", true);
RegistryKey newappkey = uninstall.CreateSubKey("Enter the name of the program here");

newappkey.SetValue("DisplayIcon", "Path to the program or icon");
newappkey.SetValue("DisplayName", "Enter the name of the program here");
newappkey.SetValue("DisplayVersion", "1.0");
newappkey.SetValue("Publisher", "Leo"); 
newappkey.SetValue("UninstallString", "Path to the uninstaller");

//I don't know if this part is necessary but I included it anyway
newappkey.Close();
```

There are also some other attributes I found in other programs that it appears you can add:

- InstallLocation (string) - Path to the main program directory.
- ModifyPath (string) - Path to the modifier (often the uninstaller with arguments).

Hexidecimals that prevent the user from doing what they say

- NoModify - 0 or 1
- NoRemove - 0 or 1
- NoRepair - 0 or 1

Estimated size

- EstimatedSize (hexidecimal) - The estimated size of the programs directory in KB converted to hexidecimal. So for example if the program is 500 MB then that will be 500,000 KB which should then be converted to 0x0007a120 which will be the final value of the Registry key.

Answer (score 1):

**Please be aware that edit registry is not perfect and risky in terms of data loss, corruption. Making a mistake could end badly.*

In case you want it simple as a batch file:

Example .bat code below will add the x64 BEAN app.

```
:: Note: Must be run as administrator
:: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN
::
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v DisplayIcon /d "E:\BEAN.exe" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v DisplayName /d "BEAN 888" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v DisplayVersion /d "2023.2" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v EstimatedSize /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v NoModify /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v NoRepair /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v Publisher /d "The gau gau LLC" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v UninstallString /d "E:\clean.bat" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BEAN" /v URLInfoAbout /d "https://wikipedia.org" /f

pause
exit
```

EstimatedSize is interesting that you can fake the real Size of the app @@
[image]

For x32 app the branch should be:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```